# SQL is this possible...it probably is

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i have 2 tables

**Places**

```
PlaceID   varchar  PK
PlaceName varchar
```

**Trips**

```
TripID      int   PK
Depart      TIME
DepartPlc   varchar
ArrivalPlc  varchar
ArrivalTime TIME
```

`DepartPlc` and `ArrivalPlc` both have `PlaceID`'s stored.

I want to select the data from trips, but show de `PlaceName` data that corresponds to the ID stored in `DepartPlc` and `ArrivalPlc`.

Anyone can help me on my way?

I currently have this statement:

```
SELECT TripID, Depart, PlaceName, ArrivalPlc, ArrivalTime 
FROM Trips, Places 
WHERE TripID = 'VALUE' AND PlaceName = DepartPlc;
```

This works as i want it to, but when i add the same thing for ArrivalPlc obviously that does not work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just JOIN Twice using two different table aliases

```
SELECT DPlaces.placeid D_PlaceID, 
       Aplaces.placeid A_PlaceID 
FROM   trips t 
       INNER JOIN places DPlaces 
               ON t.departplc = DPlaces.placename 
       INNER JOIN places APlaces 
               ON t.arrivalplc = aplaces.placename 
WHERE t.TripID = 'VALUE'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `places` table twice in your `from` clause:

```
select 
    tripId, depart, 
    departPlc as departPlaceId, dp.placeName as departPlaceName,
    arrivalPlc as arravalPlaceId, ap.placeName as arrivalPlaceName
from
    trips as t
    inner join places as dp on t.departPlc = dp.placeId
    inner join places as ap on t.arrivalPlc = ap.placeId
where
    t.tripId = 'VALUE`
```

Notice that I moved the relation conditions from the `where` clause to the `from` clause (ussing inner join) for clarity. That way you keep things cleanly separated: the relations and the filters.

Answer (score 0):

You need a second join on Trips

```
SELECT t.TripID, t.Depart, d.PlaceName AS DepartPlaceName, a.PlaceName AS ArrivalPlaceName, t.ArrivalTime
FROM Trips t, Places d, Places a
WHERE t.TripID = 'VALUE' AND t.DepartPlc = d.PlaceID AND t.ArrivalPlc = a.PlaceID
```